# Why am I getting disconnected from WiFi after about 15 minutes of use?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I am dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 on a Toshiba Portege laptop, and for some reason I lose my wireless internet connection after about 15 minutes of use on Ubunutu after booting up. I am having no problems with Windows on the same network.

Here is the information on my wireless interface from lshw. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: c4
   serial: 10:c3:c7:24:36:ba
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-26-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:44 memory:e2400000-e2401fff
```

And ifconfig output immediately after disconnecting:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:""  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-29 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:65   Missed beacon:0
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but I am connecting to a D-Link router in Germany. I typically use this machine in the US. Network security is WPA/WPA2, IPvR is set to automatic and I set IPv6 to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Also best to set your router encryption to just wpas (AES)(CCMP) only and not (TKIP).